# Which to use - systemd OR supervisor?

Tags: startup, services, systemd, supervisor

I have a plugin for alerting on elasticsearch.

This is run manually everytime

```
python -m elastalert.elastalert --verbose --rule example_frequency.yaml
```

By this way  have to dedicate a screen to it and I want it to run in the background.

This task can be done in 2 ways, either I use **Supervisor** or **systemd**.

All I have to do is write a script for any of these.

But what should I actually use in production ?

What are the pros and cons of both these ?

Answer (score 36):

For your use case, systemd is good enough.

**systemd pros:**

Comes inbuilt with OS. No need of another dependency.

Simple to use. No learning curve as it can be managed like a system service.

**supervisord pros:**

Any user can manage processes. No need to be superuser.

Has nice web interface to manage process.

Works on any distro.

More flexibility in managing process(groups, priority order).

You can read docs to know [more advantages of supervisord](http://supervisord.org/introduction.html).

Comment: systemd "simple to use" 